# python list of items (dicts) to group data

Tags: python, mysql, list

I have a list of items (dicts) that I have in a variable which was dumped from a MySQL select. Each dict in this list is a row from the MySQL Table. There is an id for each dict and there is also a specific id which can be duplicated in this list, and not always in order. I am trying to loop through this list and get all the data from the rows with similar specific IDs. I will then do something with that data like find price averages, max/min, etc. This table in MySQL is also a temp table, where I'm pulling this info, doing these calculations, then dumping it to a new MySQL table.

An example of the data in the list would be:

```
{'id': 1, 'item_id': 27, 'item_price': 1.5, 'item_length': 23, 'item_width': 12, 'item_depth': 16}
{'id': 2, 'item_id': 28, 'item_price': 1.5, 'item_length': 23, 'item_width': 12, 'item_depth': 16}
{'id': 3, 'item_id': 27, 'item_price': 1.5, 'item_length': 23, 'item_width': 12, 'item_depth': 16}
{'id': 4, 'item_id': 29, 'item_price': 1.5, 'item_length': 23, 'item_width': 12, 'item_depth': 16}
{'id': 5, 'item_id': 28, 'item_price': 1.5, 'item_length': 23, 'item_width': 12, 'item_depth': 16}
{'id': 6, 'item_id': 27, 'item_price': 1.5, 'item_length': 23, 'item_width': 12, 'item_depth': 16}
{'id': 7, 'item_id': 29, 'item_price': 1.5, 'item_length': 23, 'item_width': 12, 'item_depth': 16}
```

I want to go through each one, get all of the lines that have item_id of 27, do something with that data, then get all of the lines with item_id of 28, do something with that data, and so on.
I did try a temp_id value setting, but this would be set each time that item_id would change.

```
tempID = 0
for item in itemList:
  if item["item_id"] != tempID:
    tempID = item["item_id"]
    <gather data>
```

I think I'm on the right track with setting tempIDs, but not sure how to set them where it goes through the entire list until that same id it first saw is completed and there are no more lines left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this by organising your data based on `"item_id"`, which will help you in fetching records cleanly. Here I am grouping your data by creating a dictionary with `"item_id"` as key. Here's a *"one-liner"* using *dictionary comprehension* along with the usage of [**`sorted()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), [**`collections.groupby()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [**`operator.itemgetter()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to create the dictionary as:

```
my_list = [
    {'id': 1, 'item_id': 27, 'item_price': 1.5, 'item_length': 23, 'item_width': 12, 'item_depth': 16},
    {'id': 2, 'item_id': 28, 'item_price': 1.5, 'item_length': 23, 'item_width': 12, 'item_depth': 16},
    {'id': 3, 'item_id': 27, 'item_price': 1.5, 'item_length': 23, 'item_width': 12, 'item_depth': 16},
    {'id': 4, 'item_id': 29, 'item_price': 1.5, 'item_length': 23, 'item_width': 12, 'item_depth': 16},
    {'id': 5, 'item_id': 28, 'item_price': 1.5, 'item_length': 23, 'item_width': 12, 'item_depth': 16},
    {'id': 6, 'item_id': 27, 'item_price': 1.5, 'item_length': 23, 'item_width': 12, 'item_depth': 16},
    {'id': 7, 'item_id': 29, 'item_price': 1.5, 'item_length': 23, 'item_width': 12, 'item_depth': 16}
]

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

my_dict = {x: list(l) for x, l in groupby(sorted(my_list, key=itemgetter('item_id')), key=itemgetter('item_id'))}
```

which will return `my_dict` as:

```
{
    27: [
        {'item_price': 1.5, 'id': 1, 'item_id': 27, 'item_depth': 16, 'item_width': 12, 'item_length': 23}, 
        {'item_price': 1.5, 'id': 3, 'item_id': 27, 'item_depth': 16, 'item_width': 12, 'item_length': 23}, 
        {'item_price': 1.5, 'id': 6, 'item_id': 27, 'item_depth': 16, 'item_width': 12, 'item_length': 23}
    ], 
    28: [
        {'item_price': 1.5, 'id': 2, 'item_id': 28, 'item_depth': 16, 'item_width': 12, 'item_length': 23}, 
        {'item_price': 1.5, 'id': 5, 'item_id': 28, 'item_depth': 16, 'item_width': 12, 'item_length': 23}
    ], 
    29: [
        {'item_price': 1.5, 'id': 4, 'item_id': 29, 'item_depth': 16, 'item_width': 12, 'item_length': 23}, 
        {'item_price': 1.5, 'id': 7, 'item_id': 29, 'item_depth': 16, 'item_width': 12, 'item_length': 23}
    ]
}
```

Now you can iterate this `dict` and utilize your data as you need like:

```
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    # Do whatever you want with the data
    print("Key: {} - data: {}".format(k, str(v)))

# Prints:
#     Key: 27 - data: [{'item_price': 1.5, 'id': 1, 'item_id': 27, 'item_depth': 16, 'item_width': 12, 'item_length': 23}, {'item_price': 1.5, 'id': 3, 'item_id': 27, 'item_depth': 16, 'item_width': 12, 'item_length': 23}, {'item_price': 1.5, 'id': 6, 'item_id': 27, 'item_depth': 16, 'item_width': 12, 'item_length': 23}]
#     Key: 28 - data: [{'item_price': 1.5, 'id': 2, 'item_id': 28, 'item_depth': 16, 'item_width': 12, 'item_length': 23}, {'item_price': 1.5, 'id': 5, 'item_id': 28, 'item_depth': 16, 'item_width': 12, 'item_length': 23}]
#     Key: 29 - data: [{'item_price': 1.5, 'id': 4, 'item_id': 29, 'item_depth': 16, 'item_width': 12, 'item_length': 23}, {'item_price': 1.5, 'id': 7, 'item_id': 29, 'item_depth': 16, 'item_width': 12, 'item_length': 23}]
```

Comment: Worked like champ!

Answer (score 0):

If you can/want to use pandas, the [`pd.DataFrame.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) can be helpful.

Just use it as `item_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(itemList)` and use pandas groupby to compute the statistics